# Referencing javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

This has always been a bit confusing to me and my programming jargon isn't adequate to google it. Not even sure if the title makes sense.
For example, if I have an array of objects like so...

`var someObjects = [{type: 'apple'}, {type: 'orange'}, {type: 'banana'}];`

...and I say that...

`var theBestFruit = someObjects[2];`

but then we add another object to the beginning, shifting all the elements...

`someObjects.unshift({type: 'pear'});`

Will `theBestFruit` still reference the banana object? Or will it now be the orange? Some explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think when you add new object to the list, the address of the previous objects do not change. So it should still refer to the banana object.

Comment: You could have tested this in less time than it took to draft the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theBestFruit = someObjects[2]` will look up what is at the second (or third, if you count as a non-programmer :p ) position of `someObject`, (which is the object `{type: 'banana'}`, and assign a direct reference to this object to `theBestFruit`. The reference is not to the second object of `someObjects`. Thus, if `someObjects` change, `theBestFruit` will still be `{type: 'banana'}`.

The best way to test it would be to... test it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. pst's answer was equally informative, just saw this one first.

Answer (score 3):

Well .. try it?

Hint:

The `someObject[2]` *expression* is *eagerly evaluated* to a *value* (read: object) which is then *bound* (read: assigned to) the *variable* `theBestFruit`. Unless `theBestFruit` is re-assigned (read: bound to something else) it will always evaluate to the same *object* (read: value).

It doesn't matter if `someObjects[2]` evaluates to something else later - it doesn't affect the binding of `theBestFruit` which was determined at the time of `=` (read: assignment).

Answer (score 1):

```
> var someObjects = [{type: 'apple'}, {type: 'orange'}, {type: 'banana'}];
undefined
> var theBestFruit = someObjects[2];
undefined
> someObjects.unshift({type: 'pear'});
4
> someObjects
[ { type: 'pear' },
  { type: 'apple' },
  { type: 'orange' },
  { type: 'banana' } ]
> theBestFruit
{ type: 'banana' }
>
```